# Capture when a date range is changed in Timeline slicer and update charts

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, slicers

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to capture the event when a date range is changed within a timeline slicer.

What I am trying to accomplish is:

- I need to capture the date range change event within the timeline slicer
- have my charts updating data when the date range is changed.

What happens now is that when I change the date range in my timeline slicer the connected pivot tables are updated accordingly and instantaneously but the charts that take data from some fields of these pivot tables (**they are not pivot charts**) need a save workbook action before they can get updated with new data.

The reason why I am using charts connected to only some parts of my pivot tables is that in this way charts are more customizable than pivot charts.

Thank you in advance for pointing me towards the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to change Workbook Calculation to Automatic and just want to update the chart(s), below is the code to basically cut the chart(s) and paste them in the same place whenever the pivot table changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myChart As ChartObject
Dim myCharts As ChartObjects
Dim myChartname As String
Dim strAddress As String

Set myCharts = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

For Each myChart In myCharts
    myChartname = myChart.Name
    strAddress = myChart.TopLeftCell.Address
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(myChartname).Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range(strAddress)
Next

End Sub
```